# Can I use Craft to Manage Site Access?

Tags: users, permissions

User Access Question...

Can I use Craft to create users that can only use the site?  These users would only be viewers of the content.  They would NOT have access to Craft or any of its features.

Put another way, users login to my site and I have Craft (theoretically) setup to control their access to either the entire site or specific sections only, NOT edit or have access to any Craft features.  I don't even want them to know craft exists. '

Basically, I only want paid clients to have access to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. You can use the `{% requireLogin %}` tag at the top of any templates that you want to protect, and you can create a login form very easily to allow registered users to login and access the site:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html

Comment: To add to this answer you could also devide users by certain tiers of permission:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/tags/requirepermission.html

As mentioned there are paid and non paid clients. Might want to look into giving them both something to look at.